# Does Microsoft Security Essentials work with any browser?

Tags: ms-security-essentials

Will the The Microsoft Security Essentials work with Firefox? (I only use IE for WinXP updates.)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it will. Every time you finish download something, you'll see a virus checking being performed in the download window.

In any case, the Real-Time protection in Security Essentials will kick in even if you use another download manager or are navigating with Firefox through websites that may contain malware. The actions they may try to perform on your machine will be analyzed by MSE and this is completely independent on the browser your use.